# Facebook Graph API - Paging

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I am getting a user's posts with the Facebook API like so:

```
FB.api('/me/home', function (response) {

});
```

This returns a paging object, with two values: `previous` and `next`.

Later in my app, I want to have a button to 'load more' for pagination. So I need to use these values to load the next lot of data from the API.

My question is how I am supposed to load this data? `previous` and `next` are full length URLs which do not work with the JavaScript Graph API (`FB.api('...')`). How exactly am I supposed to use the URL it provides me with? Or is there a better way to do pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do server-side requests to 'previous' and 'next' and send the results to a client on clicking your pagination links/buttons.

**EDIT**

Or just shorten these urls. Make them relative instead of absolute

Comment: Why? I've started using the JavaScript API, so why can't I continue to use it?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh Have you tried shortening this urls? I mean make them relative instead of absolute?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh I've modified my answer